# PPPD problems no authentication from mobile operator

Tags: linux, gprs, ppp, pppd

can someone explain to me please, why one linux device with the same sim card get different conf response from mobile operater than other?

Linux board 1:

```
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xdd49f74b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4c7a56bd> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4c7a56bd> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xdd49f74b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <compress VJ 0f 01> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <compress VJ 0f 01> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
```

Linux board 2

```
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xe6ed6383> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xe3dbfb> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x0 <auth pap>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xe6ed6383> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xe3dbfb> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xe3dbfb> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xe6ed6383]
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="" password=<hidden>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2 magic=0xe3dbfb]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xe3dbfb e6 ed 63 83]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
```

Why would one pppd dialer get back `[IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]`

And one without auth request?

Why what does it send to mobile operator that mobile operator returns different response?

Same sim card, two different boards? And as expected on board authentication never works...

Any ideas?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Maybe try this question on another SE site like SuperUser?